# Nexmo error Builder#withClaim() is meant to be used for non-registered claims, check the documentation on how to set claim "sub"

Tags: php, laravel, vonage

I can't generate jwt from provided claims. this my code:

```
$keypair = new \Vonage\Client\Credentials\Keypair(file_get_contents(storage_path('voip/vonage/private.key')), env('NEXMO_APPLICATION_ID'));
    $client = new \Vonage\Client($keypair);

    $claims = [
      'exp' => strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+24 Hours'))),
      'sub' => 'apg-cs',
      'acl' => [
        'paths' => [
          '/*/users/**' => (object) [],
          '/*/conversations/**' => (object) [],
          '/*/sessions/**' => (object) [],
          '/*/devices/**' => (object) [],
          '/*/image/**' => (object) [],
          '/*/media/**' => (object) [],
          '/*/applications/**' => (object) [],
          '/*/push/**' => (object) [],
          '/*/knocking/**' => (object) [],
          '/*/legs/**' => (object) [],
        ]
      ],
    ];
    $token = $client->generateJwt($claims);
    return $token->toString();
```

the error:

```
Builder#withClaim() is meant to be used for non-registered claims, check the documentation on how to set claim "sub"
```

when i remove the "sub" from claims, vonage will thrown error :

```
user:error:invalid-user
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug. The JWT library we use changed quite a few things between v3 and v4, and this looks like one of them. Since the Conversation API is still considered Beta this compatibility wasn't checked, but I'll make sure it works.

I've opened a github issue at https://github.com/Vonage/vonage-php-sdk-core/issues/276c and will get this fixed ASAP.

Comment: Yeah you right, to get rid of this error i downgraded vonage/client to "vonage/client": "^2.0", and set JWT to "lcobucci/jwt": "3.3.*"